# Visual Studio 2019 winforms custom control designer problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a Visual Studio 2019 / Windows Forms problem.
I'm getting - "A chart element with the name 'ChartArea1' already exists in the 'ChartAreaCollection'."
So - what am I trying to do...
I have created a custom control derived from System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.
I call it XChart.
I want to have a custom chart with predefined properties/areas/axis/colors/legends/series 
that will show up in the Toolbox when designing new forms.
Everything works except for one thing, and that is NOT just for this control, 
it seems to be a general designer problem that probably has been around forever.
As fast as I change ANYTHING in my form all the control properties get written down
into MyForm.InitializeComponent(), which in turn makes all this below appear twice for the same chart - giving the error.
The properties values don't stay in the custom control, they get copied all of them to the form, even though I
haven't changed one of them.

It can't even be properly done with a TextBox.
Let's say I create a custom control called XTextBox inherited from TextBox.
The XTextBox.BackColor is default set to - let's say - Red.
I then use this XTextBox in a number of places in my app.
After a while I want to change my default BackColor to Yellow.
So I change the XTextBox.BackColor to Yellow in my custom control and nothing happens
because it still says Red in all my forms.

Any good ideas?

This is ruffly what my XChart.InitializeComponent() (and MyForm.InitializeComponent()) looks like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea area = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series serie0 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series serie1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title title = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title();
// 
// XChart
// 
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
area.AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaShell;
area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.000";
area.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
area.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
area.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
area.AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
area.AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
area.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
area.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.None;
area.AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
area.AxisX.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
area.AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 16D;
area.AxisX2.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
area.AxisX2.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
area.AxisX2.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.None;
area.AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaShell;
area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0.000";
area.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
area.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
area.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
area.AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
area.AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dot;
area.AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
area.AxisY.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
area.AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
area.AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.None;
area.AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
area.AxisY.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
area.AxisY.ScrollBar.Size = 16D;
area.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
area.Name = "ChartArea1";
area.Position.Auto = false;
area.Position.Height = 97F;
area.Position.Width = 90F;
area.Position.Y = 3F;
this.ChartAreas.Add(area);
legend.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
legend.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaShell;
legend.Name = "Legend1";
legend.TitleForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
this.Legends.Add(legend);
this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 149);
this.Name = "chart1";
serie0.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
serie0.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
serie0.Legend = "Legend1";
serie0.Name = "0";
serie1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
serie1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
serie1.Legend = "Legend1";
serie1.Name = "1";
this.Series.Add(serie0);
this.Series.Add(serie1);
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
this.TabIndex = 3;
this.Text = "chart1";
title.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaShell;
title.Name = "Title1";
title.Position.Auto = false;
title.Position.Height = 2.59811F;
title.Position.Width = 94F;
title.Position.Y = 1F;
title.Text = "Titles[0]";
this.Titles.Add(title);
this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.OnMouseDown);
this.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.OnMouseUp);
```

Comment: _I change the XTextBox.BackColor to Yellow in my custom control and nothing happens_ The Designer doesn't pick it up immediately, but at runtime or after a restart the new color shows, no?

Comment: Do you editing any of designer generated files (`*.Designer.cs`)?

Comment: The answers to that is no and no.
A property change in the custom control is overridden by the "old" property value in forms.Designer.cs

Comment: The Form designer adds a few basic elements by default. This happens upon form initialization so you can't prevent it from you custom chart's constructor. So the best solution would be to prevent the designer to help you out this way. Not sure if there is an atttribute to do that. Note that it won't happen if you add the chart in code instead; but then you can't edit it in the desgner..

Comment: The is the normal behavior. What you define in your Control's initialization procedure are the default values of your control. When you create an instance, dropping a control on a Form, the Form will provide means to modify these defaults with the PropertyGrid. The new settings are stored in the Form's `InitializeComponent` method. If you change a default value in the class object, it applies to new instances of the control, not the one that has already beed modified and already serialized using the PropertyGrid in the Form's designer. Delete the control and drop another in this case.

Comment: This will be always the case while your Control is not in a *stable* state (you're not done developing it and you're changing the behavior of properties that are subject to serialization). If you don't want a property value to be serialized or you want to modify the way it's serialized, add a `[DesignerSerializationVisibility]` attribute to the property, `[DefaultValue]` attribute and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal situation. You can solve it by rebuilding the project. After you rebuild it and drag a new one onto the Form, it will be "Yellow".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an article on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973818(v=msdn.10)) that shows a ways to customize auto-generated code. Among other things it suggests using `DesignerSerializationVisiblityAttribute`, `DefaultValueAttribute` and `ShouldSerialize<Property Name>` method to suppress/force code generation.

Another way to customize the generated code is implementation of a custom `CodeDomSerializer` on the control. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer?view=netframework-4.8) for details

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. Maybe it will take me somewhere.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. I won't say it's nice and easy but with attributes for serializing and default values it's doable.
Thanks Sergey!